# Is motor size an important factor in output performance or torque by keeping the same consumed power and voltage?

Tags: power, motor, torque, performance, comparison

I have a problem comparing two sample motor's performance metrics .

Two motors with same wattage ang voltage but different size.

1. Big bulky motor Example: [Bosch 1250 W](https://www.bosch-home.com/ne/product-list/kitchen-machines/food-processors/multitalent-8/MC812M865#/Togglebox=manuals/Togglebox=accessories/)

- [Size Ref #1 **1380 W**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmDdZxM9neY)
- [Size Ref #2 **950 W**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FUfn2EbC14c)
- [Size Ref #3 **700 W**](https://youtu.be/YSYwu_3IDA8?si=PBZaFI6Ylx4vTLzK&t=101)

2. Slim and small motor Example: [Braun **1200 W**](https://www.braunhousehold.com/en/multiquick-9-hand-blender-mq-9195xli/p/HB901-MQ9195XLI)

- [Size Ref #5](https://youtu.be/EAgMf5x7aXw?si=JJX4W61Q5mZp5ty5)
- [Size Ref #6](https://youtu.be/gri9J57dFMg?si=_uk8qUXTn-UdYwXL&t=312)

These two motors have the same power draw (one is 1250 W and the other is 1200 W,) but their sizes are hugely different from each other. I know that mechanical power [torque * speed] and electrical power [voltage * current] relate to each other by efficiency factor that I assume for these two should not be different very much.

What I don’t understand is how these two could do the same with hugely distinct size and form factor. I think that the bigger size should do more, but I do not understand the physics behind it, and I might be wrong in thinking so.

How can these two differ in performance with the same power draw? Is there a job that the bigger one will prevail over the smaller one? Could someone compare these two in any performance related metric?

Is there any other factor that yields more performance which needs
bigger size or is it just related to inefficiency?

---

***Update***

After a little more research, I've found out that the type of motor could be a major factor in its frame size. As an example, BLDC motors have smaller form factor due to the lack of windings for stator and using permanent magnets whereas induction motor due to the need for both stator and rotor windings have bigger frame and form factor.

I think the difference in size I've noticed in the two mentioned forms above, is because the first ones probably use induction whereas the second one uses BLDC motors.

Comment: How do you know the `size and form factor` of each of the motors? I didn't even find *motor* mentioned with 1..

Comment: I've linked each motor examples in front of them but actually they closed my question for being off-topic otherwise I would have added more details.
I've seen these motors by searching through the internet by repair tag added to the model number. Also, by looking at the examples Pics linked in the post you could guess that the heavy base is not just for weight balance or being empty and the bulky food processor realy has a bigger motor.

Comment: Add any information you have. Flag for reopening.

Comment: I've applied for reopening but it's still under review after hours.

Comment: Yes, you are right by the rules and guidelines. but i think the main question is still valid which is "does increase in size would be a lot help for the performance of motors with same wattage and voltage?"

Comment: Spelling out what aspects of *performance* you want discussed should invite useful answers: Temperature rise vs. time&mechanical power, air flow caused/needed, rotational acceleration & smoothness, vibration&sound, EMC…

Answer (score 1):

The food processor of course needs a base big enough to support a work bowl while an immersion blender has no such constraints. Quite the opposite: the smaller and lighter it can be made, the easier it will be to use. So Bosch might have gone with a larger, heavier, and cheaper motor for their food processor while Braun might have spent more for smaller, lighter, and more expensive motor. It's hard to do a side-by-side cost comparison since the price includes the accessories.

Also keep in mind that manufacturers will put down whatever performance numbers they can just barely legally back up so the watt values given might be "peak" numbers that will never be seen in actual use or something like that.

Comment: I understand what you said but the main question remains for me here is if the numbers are not just for advertisement, how size affects the performance if wattage and voltage are the same for two motors. Could this difference be just inefficiency or size is an important factor in performance? I've also added some size reference Links after each type.